# Form code trying to run during MAKEMIGRATONS

Tags: django

I am attempting to setup my new website that works fine locally.

However, when I deploy, there is some code in one of my forms that is causing an issue:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
address1 = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
address2 = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
city = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
state = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
zip_code = forms.CharField(max_length=25)

CHOICES = tuple((o.pk, o.name) for o in Allergen.objects.all())
allergens = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, required=False)
```

The problem is the last 2 lines. When I attempt to MAKEMIGRATIONS, I get this error that the Allergens model is missing. However, if I remove these 2 lines, there is no issue.

I suppose, I can just comment out the lines, then add them back. But there must be a better way.

How can I do makemigrations without it trying to  run these lines?

Comment: That is one of the many reasons why you should use a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` with a `queryset=...`, since that will not run (the queries are performed *lazily*).

Comment: You have to understand that `class` statements are executable statements, so all the code at the top-level of your class statement IS indeed executed when the module is first imported (as well as all code at the module's top-level). That's how Python works (that's even part of the language specs IIRC), so there's no way to avoid this - and as mentionned by Willem Wan Onsem, this will not produce the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better *not* to run queries in a class definition *at all*. Besides the problems when making migrations, the tuple will *not* be updated if a new `Allergen` is added or some `Allergen` is removed from the database. So you run the query once when the file where the class is defined is processed (that is often when the webserver is started), and then that value is used.

You can make use of a [**`ModelMultipleChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) and use the [**`queryset=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField.queryset) to obtain the items:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    address1 = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    address2 = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip_code = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    allergens = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Allergen.objects.all(),
        required=False
    )
```

This will not only *postpone* the retrieval of the objects, but furthermore your form field will "understand" the concept of a model object, and thus have a "richer" way to handle the data.

In order to display the correct name, you might have to update the `__str__` method of your `Allergen` model to:

```
class Allergen(models.Model):
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: I hereby nominate this "I think it would be better" for the "understatement of the year" award !-)

Comment: "you run the query once when the database is started" => when the forms module is first imported, actually.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: sorry, that should have been "when the webserver is started" (well indeed when the module is imported is better).

Comment: Thanks.  I will also take the advice from someone else not to put code in my class declarations.